# Llamada a AJAX queda en vacío tras cargar archivo php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario que realiza una acción php y su valida y muestra mensanjes de confirmación o error mediante jQuery. La acción php la realiza sin problema, manda un correo. Pero ni la validación ni los mensajes de confirmación/error se muestran, es decir, javascript no está funcionando. Las rutas a los scripts son:

(/js/contact.js) (/assets/contact_process.php) (/contacto.php)

El código php es:

```html
<?php

  $to = "correo@hotmail.com";
  $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
  $cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

  $headers = "From: $from";
 $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

  $subject = "Nuevo Mensaje Formulario de contacto Imclpsicología";

 $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='es'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Express Mail</title></head><body>";
 $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
 $body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
 $body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
 $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Nombre:</strong> {$name}</td>";
 $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
  $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Teléfono:</strong> {$number}</td>";
 $body .= "</tr>";
 $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Asunto:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
 $body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
 $body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
 $body .= "</tbody></table>";
 $body .= "</body></html>";

  mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
  
?>
```

El código javascript y html en contacto.php es:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    (function($) {
          "use strict";

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value)
    }, "type the correct answer -_-");

    // validate contactForm form
    $(function() {
        $('#contactForm').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                number: {
                    required: false,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "come on, you have a name, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "come on, you have a subject, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your subject must consist of at least 4 characters"
                },
                number: {
                    required: "come on, you have a number, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your Number must consist of at least 5 characters"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "no email, no message"
                },
                message: {
                    required: "um...yea, you have to write something to send this form.",
                    minlength: "thats all? really?"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    url:"/assets/contact_process.php",
                    success: function() {
                        $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                            $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                            $('#success').fadeIn();
                            $('.modal').modal('hide');
                   $('#success').modal('show');
                        })
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                            $('#error').fadeIn();
                            $('.modal').modal('hide');
                   $('#error').modal('show');
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
 })(jQuery)
})
```

```css
/* Contact Success and error Area css
============================================================================================ */
.success-contact h5 {
  color:#4267b2;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.error-contact h5 {
  color:#4267b2;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.modal-message .modal-dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) !important;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) !important;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) !important;
  margin: 0px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-message .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.modal-message .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-message .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header h2 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2bc0a4;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.modal-message .modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-header p {
  display: block;
}

/* End Contact Success and error Area css
```

```html
<!-- Contact js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha256-F6h55Qw6sweK+t7SiOJX+2bpSAa3b/fnlrVCJvmEj1A=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pjr1OlpZMY6qesJM68t2v39t+lMLvxwpa8QlRjJroA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/js/contact.js"></script>

<form class="contact_us_form row" action="/assets/contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Teléfono">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Asunto">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="1" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn submit_btn2 form-control">Enviar mensaje</button>
   </div>
 </form>
 
    <!--================Contact Success and Error message Area =================-->
      <div class="success-contact">
        <div id="success" class="modal modal-message fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        </button>
                        <h2>Gracias</h2>
                        <p>Su mensaje ha sido enviado...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <!-- Modals error -->
    <div class="error-contact">
        <div id="error" class="modal modal-message fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        </button>
                        <h2>Lo sentimos</h2>
                        <p>Algo salió mal</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muchisimo codigo para leer, pero por una vista rapida pede ser porque no estas dando una respuesta. La funcion mail devuelve true o false si mal no recuerdo; seria bueno que terminaras to codigo PHP de la siguiente forma.

```
$response = array('result' => 'success');
$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if (!$send)
    $response['result'] = 'fail';

echo json_encode($response);
die();
```

luego ya por js puedes tomar los valores de la respuesta para añadir mensages, recuerda que los metodos de ajax success y error se toman consederando de si se pudo hacer la peticion o no, no si su resultado fue satisfactorio de cara al usuario

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ha sido muy clarificadora.

Answer (score 1):

No estas retornando nada desde el contact_process.php, prueba

```
echo "success";
```

o cualquier otro mensaje luego de la funcion mail para que se ejecute el success del ajax en tu js